# Special Pattern by SQL LIKE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need special pattern for finding values that are 13 length chars, first of 12 are numbers for example `119910023525P`
There are 2 Pattern :

```
LIKE '____________P'
```

or

```
LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]P'
```

Need something as `'[0-9]{12}P'`
It's Possible In MS-SQL Server ?

Comment: What's wrong with LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]P'?

Comment: @pmbAustin there isn't any wrong with it, just asking if sql server support regular expressions inside the query. `[0-9]{12}P` is better than that when your query is too long.

Comment: @pmbAustin that isn't very human readable. In order to deduce that pattern is looking for 12 digits followed by a P you need to count them all up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no quantifiers in the TSQL pattern syntax.

You can use

```
LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]',12) + 'P'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this logic:

```
(x like '%P' and x not like '%[^0-9]%P' and len(x) = 13)
```

But that is about the same amount of typing as just manually replicated `[0-9]` 12 times.

Comment: good answered but as you say replicated `[0-9]` 12 times is shorter than it =))

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the REGEXP() function will help you with this task.

Comment: this is not a sql server function